# Can we allow unsigned Certificate during Installation and still run the Marketing automation service

Tags: sitecore-install-framework, marketing-automation

I am trying to install Sitecore 9.3 using the PowerShell scripts "XP0-SingleDeveloper.ps1".
The script stops the installation and throws error on starting the Marketing Automation service.

> Waiting for service 'Sitecore Marketing Automation Engine - OnePOC.xconnect-MarketingAutomationService
> (OnePOC.xconnect-MarketingAutomationService)' to start...
> Install-SitecoreConfiguration : Failed to start service 'Sitecore Marketing Automation Engine -
> OnePOC.xconnect-MarketingAutomationService (OnePOC.xconnect-MarketingAutomationService)'.

I am aware about this issue and one solution. This occurs when there is an un-signed certificate in root of cert store. I know about the PowerShell script that will move the certificate in a different location and the installation will work. I fixed this issue multiple times in previous project and wrote a blog as well https://darjimaulik.wordpress.com/2020/07/20/sitecore-xconnect-certificate-error-http-response-was-not-successful-forbidden/

But this time, **I want to install Sitecore 9.3 *without moving the certificate* and XConnect must work.
I am looking for some option to Allow Invalid certificate during the installation.**

I have 2 more installation earlier on the same machine and when I ran the script earlier, It found a Certificate and moved it. This certificate is for our VPN connection. Moving that created some major issues in security. I want to avoid the same issue again.

The Answer mentioned at [Sitecore 9.3 Installation failing - 'Failed to start the Marketing Automation Engine service](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/27214/sitecore-9-3-installation-failing-failed-to-start-the-marketing-automation-en) Does not help in my case.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the marketing automation startservice in `xconnect-xp0.json` and continue with your installation. once installation is completed, you can start the service manually.