# Sitecore 9.3 Installing on Windows 11 returns "certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted." error

Tags: installation

I know some people's first thoughts will be `Sitecore 9.3` is not supported on `Windows 11` [per their documentation](https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0087164). And that is fair but it can be done and can still work.

However, there are a few challenges. The installation does not work out of the box because Windows 11 have started to [enforce a security change Microsoft has rolled out](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/connect/error-message-when-you-connect). This change makes connections to the SQL server default to use encrypted connections. This means some of the Powershell scripts in the install error with this error.

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.)

It errors because the cert is self-signed and is not fully trusted. So is there a way to address this so the installs run?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I have been working through this and found the solution. But I wanted to post the write-up here so others can find it in the future.

The main issue on why this errors comes the xConnect scripts in the `sitecore-XP0.json` file. There are 4 `InvokeSqlcmd` configured in this json file that look like this.

```
            "Description": "Create Collection Shard Database Server Login.",
            "Type": "InvokeSqlcmd",
            "Params": {
                "ServerInstance": "[parameter('SqlServer')]",
                "Credential": "[variable('Sql.Credential')]",
                "InputFile": "[variable('Sharding.SqlCmd.Path.CreateShardApplicationDatabaseServerLogin')]",
                "Variable": [
                    "[concat('UserName=',variable('SqlCollection.User'))]",
                    "[concat('Password=',variable('SqlCollection.Password'))]"
                ]
            },
            "Skip": "[parameter('SkipDatabaseInstallation')]"
```

Normally these work fine. Except now with Windows 11 these call default to using an encrypted connection to SQL. This means it is using a self-signed cert that is not going to be trusted. So is there a way we can make these calls not need the cert? [There sure is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17615260/the-certificate-chain-was-issued-by-an-authority-that-is-not-trusted-when-conn). We just need to use `"TrustServerCertificate": true`. So we need to update each of the 4 calls to look like this (this is the update to one of them they all don't need to look like this they all just need to have `"TrustServerCertificate": true,` added to them.

```
            "Description": "Create Collection Shard Database Server Login.",
            "Type": "InvokeSqlcmd",
            "Params": {
                "ServerInstance": "[parameter('SqlServer')]",
                "TrustServerCertificate": true,
                "Credential": "[variable('Sql.Credential')]",
                "InputFile": "[variable('Sharding.SqlCmd.Path.CreateShardApplicationDatabaseServerLogin')]",
                "Variable": [
                    "[concat('UserName=',variable('SqlCollection.User'))]",
                    "[concat('Password=',variable('SqlCollection.Password'))]"
                ]
            },
            "Skip": "[parameter('SkipDatabaseInstallation')]"
```

Notice the minor but very important change here of the additional params item. Once you add this your installation will work.

There are a couple more issues you may run into and I will link their solutions here as well to make it easier.

1. [Marketing service will not start](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/27214/sitecore-9-3-installation-failing-failed-to-start-the-marketing-automation-en)
2. [ERR_SSL_KEY_USAGE_INCOMPATIBLE](https://www.maartenwillebrands.nl/2021/11/15/sitecore-running-sitecore-on-windows-11/)

Comment: Thank you @ToddB, it helps me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 8):

For installing Sitecore 10.3 I was getting similar error as shown below :

[image]

The solution is to add `"TrustServerCertificate": true`, in 4 places in `xconnect-xp0.json` (and in 1 place in `sitecore-XPO.json` if you are using Azure SQL ) as shown below :

[image]

[image]

Also, in SSMS check the `Trust server certificate` checkbox

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This issue occurs even for `Windows 10 Sitecore v9.3`, solution mentioned adding `"TrustServerCertificate": true`, in 4 places in `xconnect-xp0.json`should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

If you facing a similar issue for a `Sitecore 10.3 XP1 Scaled` instance. Search for the keyword `InvokeSqlcmd` in the json file `xconnect-xp1-collection.json` set `"TrustServerCertificate": true` at 4 places and in json file `xconnect-xp1-cm.json` make the same change at 1 place.

[image]