# Unable to install Sitecore 10.1.2 in Windows 11 Pro

Tags: installation

I'm trying to install the `Graphical setup package for XP Single (Sitecore 10.1 Update 2)` on a new laptop which has `Windows 11 Pro` with `SQL Server 2022 16.0.1050`.

This is the error during the installation:

[image]

Sitecore support has informed that:

> Sitecore 10.1 is not compatible with Windows 11 and have never been
> tested with Windows 11

Unfortunately, I do not have access to another machine with Windows 10.

Added the `"TrustServerCertificate": true` following this [post](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/34587/sitecore-9-3-installing-on-windows-11-returns-certificate-chain-was-issued-by-a), but it's the same error.

Is it possible to disable the security SSL check in the Operating system or any other way/hack to complete the installation.

We have 10.1.2 in PRD and that is why I wanted to have the same version on my local machine.

Answer (score 1):

You can give it a try below solutions if that resolves your problem. As per the Microsoft SQL troubleshooting page ([Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/connect/certificate-chain-not-trusted?tabs=ole-db-driver-19)).

There are 2 more solutions:

1. Use Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server 18.x. You can download the driver from [Release notes for the Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/release-notes-for-oledb-driver-for-sql-server).
2. If the application connection string property already specifies a value of `Yes` or `Mandatory` for the `Encrypt/Use Encryption for Data setting`, change the value to `No` or `Optional`. For example, `Use Encryption for Data=Optional`. If the connection string doesn't specify any value for `Encrypt/Use Encryption for Data`, add `Use Encryption for Data=Optional` to the connection string. For more information, see [Encryption and certificate validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/features/encryption-and-certificate-validation).

The change must be done as explained in this article by adding "Encrypt": "Optional" to 4 instances of Invoke-SqlCmd in xConnect-xp0.json:

https://navansitecorenotes.blogspot.com/2023/06/windows-11-pro-sitecore-101x.html

Hope it helps!

Comment: Could you please tell me where can I find this conn string in the installation package

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it will solve your issue but you can also try disabling the `TLS 1.3` from your entire system. To do this you need to run the below Powershell script.

```
New-Item `
   'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.3\Server' `
   -Force | Out-Null
    
New-ItemProperty `
   -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.3\Server' `
   -name 'Enabled' -value '0' -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null
    
New-ItemProperty `
   -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.3\Server' `
   -name 'DisabledByDefault' -value 1 -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null
```

Try this and see if it works for you.

Another thing you can also try adding a few parameters to your connection string like `encrypt=false`. To do this if you open your installation folder, there is a file called `spe.json`. You can see that under "Variables" it is trying to create the connection string. Try adding the values. Not sure if it will work but you can try.

Comment: This did not work. How can I enable TLS again?

Comment: Go to the Registry Editor and open the path given in the script above and enable it. Here HKLM means HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE also refer to this for more details. https://www.asustor.com/en-gb/knowledge/detail/?id=&group_id=1011